# Override image tag with multiple docker-compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The issue I have is that my attempts to override `image` are being ignored when I build/run the `rails` service. The name of the image retained is `okamii/paas:dev`. But if I build/run the `app` service, the name of the image is the expected one whether I override it (`okamii/paas:ci`) or not (`okamii/paas:dev`).

Am I missing something?

The command I use:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.ci.yml up -d rails
```

These are the two Compose files I am using:

shortened `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app: &app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.1.4'
        NODE_MAJOR: '12'
        PG_MAJOR: '13'
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.7.2-jemalloc'
        YARN_VERSION: '1.22.5'
        BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE: 1
        S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "${ACCESS_KEY:?err}"
        S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "${SECRET_KEY:?err}"
    image: okamii/paas:dev
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp

  backend: &backend
    <<: *app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
      - rails_cache:/app/tmp/cache
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - packs:/app/public/packs
      - .dockerdev/.psqlrc:/root/.psqlrc:ro
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-development}
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432
      - BOOTSNAP_CACHE_DIR=/usr/local/bundle/_bootsnap
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpacker
      - HISTFILE=/app/log/.bash_history
      - PSQL_HISTFILE=/app/log/.psql_history
      - EDITOR=vi
      - MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2
      - WEB_CONCURRENCY=${WEB_CONCURRENCY:-1}
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy

  rails:
    <<: *backend
    entrypoint: ./.dockerdev/rails-entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

full `docker-compose.ci.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app: &app
    build:
      cache_from:
        - okamii/paas:ci
    image: okamii/paas:ci
```

Answer (score 1):

The YAML anchor syntax (`&app`, `*backend`) is local to a specific file, and interpreted when the YAML reader reads a file in.  That means your main `docker-compose.yml` file, once Compose actually starts looking at it, has three separate services with three separate `image:` lines.  The second file has its own `&app` anchor (which is never referenced), and only declares a single image.

```yaml
# Base docker-compose.yml, after YAML anchor expansion
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: okamii/paas:dev
  backend:
    image: okamii/paas:dev
  rails:
    image: okamii/paas:dev
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.ci.yml, after YAML anchor expansion
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: okamii/paas:ci
```

If the only thing you're trying to override is the image tag, you can use an [environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) for this.  This will also work well if you're using a unique image tag per build, which is generally a good practice.

```yaml
# Base docker-compose.yml file
services:
  app: &app
    image: okamii/paas:${TAG:-latest}
```

```yaml
# There is no docker-compose.ci.yml file
```

```sh
TAG=ci docker-compose up -d
```

If you really want to specify it in a separate YAML file, you'll need to recreate the YAML anchor structure there, or otherwise ensure that all of the services have their values specified.

```yaml
# docker-compose.ci.yml, the complex version
version: 3.8
services:
  app: &app
    image: okamii/paas:ci
  backend: &backend
    <<: *app
  rails:
    <<: *backend
```

You might also consider ways to simplify this setup.  There are a *lot* of options in this build, and most of them can probably be fixed in the Dockerfile (for instance, the `BUNDLER_VERSION` must match *exactly* what's in the `Gemfile.lock` file; there is no reason to specify this externally).  It's also typical practice to use the same Docker image in all environments and not build a special CI-only image.